# How would I define a page route for this url routing condition:

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

How would I create a page route to handle requests for pages that match this url:   "^~/PPP/(.*).aspx" ?

I tried this but requests like ~/ppp/sompage.aspx are not redirected to ~/content.aspx:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
          "View Archive",           // Route name
          "ppp/{query}.aspx/{*querystring}", // Route URL
          "~/content.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
          );
```

Comment: Simple fix - took another look and I noticed a prior rule for another page route was intercepting requests for these pages.  All I needed to do was rearrange the order the routes appeared and all was good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the order of your page routes.  The above route was never hit because a prior rule also matched.